# How do I use a Google Apps account for Open ID logins?

Tags: openid, google-openid

I use my Google Account for logging into OpenID-enabled websites. In my website, I added the following meta tags:

When I then use my website URL (http://blog.dantup.com) in an OpenID login, it redirects me to a Google login page, which requires that I login as "danny.tuppeny", and sends me back. Logging in as another Google account doesn't work.

Recently, I noticed I was able to login to another OpenID site using a Google Apps user (user@mydomain.com). If possible, I would like to amend my meta tags, so that Google requires my Google Apps user instead of the Google "danny.tuppeny" user. This is because now that Google supports Apps users for most services, I'm trying to migrate most things to my Apps account.

So... What do I need to change the meta tags to in order to use user@mydomain.com. Currently Apps accounts don't have Google Profiles URLs, however since I can login to other services (eg. Disqus) by clicking the Google logo and logging in as user@mydomain.com, I presume this is still possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Google+ went live for Google Apps yesterday, this is now possible! Just put your profile URL for `openid2.local_id`. Eg, this is what I have in the `<head>` section at [blog.dantup.com](http://blog.dantup.com/):

```
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?source=profiles">
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="https://plus.google.com/113181962167438638669">
```

This allows me to use 'http://blog.dantup.com/' to login to sites like StackOverflow using my associated Google Apps account, and they'll receive 'http://blog.dantup.com/' as my identifier, allowing me to change to a non-Google account in the future (if required) without updating lots of websites!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your problem clearly but try this :

```
$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=YourDomain.com';
```

This will take you to the login page of your google apps account !

Comment: Yep, that works - but I'm after what I need to put into my meta-tag so this works with my custom url :(

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? URL will change for sure. No way you can prevent that !

Comment: I want to use my own URL (eg. "dantup.com") as my open ID login, so I'm not tied to using my Google Account. This way I can make sure the URL/Identifier will *NOT* change. It works fine for Google Accounts, but I would like to simply do the same thing with my "Google Apps" account. More info on delegation here: http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#delegating_authentication